# col-xs не срабатывает на моб. телефоне

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Не срабатывает стиль `col-xs-12` при просмотре со смартфона, но, когда меняешь масштаб в браузере на десктопе (например 200%), то все нормально.

Код:

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        Block 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        Block 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        Block 3
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        Block 4
      </div>
      ...

    </div>
    <!--row-->
  </header>
  ...
</div>
<!--container-->
```

То же самое, когда добавлял код адаптивного меню (гамбургер не получается при изменении меньше 768px).

Когда смотрю код в браузере в CSS, пишет, что перечеркнут:

```css
col-xs-12 {widh:100%}
```

Нужно, чтобы на экранах более 1200px и от 980px до 1200px было 4 колонки, на экранах от 768px до 979px было 2 колонки, а менее 768px - 1 колонка.

Comment: _class="**col-xs-12** col-sm-6 col-md-3 **col-xs-3**"_ - ты уж определись 3 или 12

Comment: Извиняюсь. class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3

Comment: ну так может у тебя такая же опечатка и в коде? :-) Если стиль перечернут, ищи тот который применился и смотри откуда он

Comment: проверь еще наличие meta-тега с указанием поведения браузера

Comment: нет в коде все нормально я здесь писал вручную. :-)

Comment: _Если стиль перечернут, ищи тот который применился и смотри откуда он_

Comment: помогла вставка: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!